# how to pass the API JSON response parameters to material ui table

Tags: javascript, json, api, material-ui, material-table

I'm trying to create the a table using the material UI and i would like to create the rows based on the API response data but the problem is i get array of object with more paramters but i need to filter out few paramters and create a array of json objected so that table gets constructed automatically.

Actual JSON response:

```
{
    "items": [{
            "name": "banana",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to reduce it to

```
[{
            "name": "banana",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "value": 10
        }]
```

so that i can pass the data to my material table like below.

```
<MaterialTable
      title="Transaction Summary"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data} *array of object will be passed here*
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may get the idea from below code just use map function and pass the desire number of columns

```
<MaterialTable
          title="Transaction Summary"
          columns={state.columns}
          data={state.data.map( item => key={item.key}>{item.value} )}
        />
```

Comment: this too...Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Your column array should be like this

```
let columns = [
    {
        title: "Fruit Name", // this will be column name in <th>
        field:"name", // this name should match key in data array
    },
    {
        title: "value", // column heading
        field: "value", //should match with data object
    }
]
```

```
const apiResponse = {
    items: [
        {
            name: "banana",
            id: 1,
            value: 10,
        },
        {
            name: "banana",
            id: 1,
            value: 10,
        },
        {
            name: "banana",
            id: 1,
            value: 10,
        },
    ],
};

// format it

const formatedData = apiResponse.items.map((item)=>{
    return {
        name: item.name,
        value: item.value
    }
})
```

Then, use it

```
<MaterialTable
  title="Transaction Summary"
  columns={columns}
  data={formatedData}
/>
```

Comment: My api response is like this and i want to remove the paramter id and recreate the object. is there any way ? `{
    "items": [{
            "name": "banana",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "banana",
            "id": 1,
            "value": 10
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: @vivek.p.nmanu i have updated the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass in 1 level deeper? Instead of data={response} try data={response.items}